# How to print the same time in milliseconds in python and C++?

Tags: python, c++, time

I have a python program that uses C++ library calls. I can modify the program and the library. Library is living it's own life: it spins up threads and handles events at it's own pace. Every once in a while synchronization appears. I want to print time in python and in library and asses which points preceed which in both code snippets. Is there a consistent way to get time in python and C++ that can be compared/ordered?

I am looking for a method to have a millisecond precision. I want C++ time and Python to have exactly the same reference point - system time or smth.

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Unrelated: It's not easy to get millisecond-precise timing on a desktop computer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the unix timestamp.

Python:

```
import time

int(time.time()) // Outputs something like 1572484509
```

C++

```
std::time(nullptr); // Outputs something like 1572484509
```

Comment: these are not milliseconds. `1572484509` is the epoch time in __seconds__